Transit visa requirement for T4 to T2 London Heathrow to travel to Dublin
Do I need a transit visa to transit from T4 to T2 in London Heathrow? I have approximately 2 hours of transit time. The destination is Dublin.

We know nothing about you. Specifically, we know nothing about your citizenship/residency/currently valid visas in your passport.

The factors listed in littleadv's comment are usually relevant and sometimes determinative of whether or not a traveler needs a visa.
